# Execute codemagic build after gitlab pipeline job was executed

Tags: flutter, codemagic

We have gitlab pipeline for our project and after last job executed I want to launch codemagic build. I need it to execute mobile tests after backend is deployed.
So I don't need to execute codemagic immediatly after push, pull request update or tag creation. Is it possible with codemagic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one workaround to add automatic triggers from custom sources and it should work for gitlab also:

Call these from amazon lambda function
`POST https://api.codemagic.io/builds`

```
 "appId": "----appId----",
 "workflowId": "-----workflowId-----,
 "branch": "masters"
}
```

header: `x-auth-token: -----id-----`

x-auth-token you can get from us privately.

WorkflowId and appId you can find from your settings! Its under build status badge, in badge markdown. AppId is the first serial number and workdlowid is the second one:
[image: Id placement example]